# How to create image buttons that scale across multiple resolutions?

Tags: blackberry

Is there a standard methodolgy for scaling image buttons using one image size across multiple blackberry phone model screen resolutions ?

I'm resizing encoded iamges based on display width.
So to resize an image to a quarter length of the screen I do -

```
imageLength = Dislay.getWidth / 4;
```

Is there something better ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you need.

Do you want to scale an image? If so, take a look at [scaleImage32(int, int)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/EncodedImage.html#scaleImage32%28int,%20int%29) method. Also, you should use methods from the [Fixed32](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/math/Fixed32.html) class to calculate image sizes.

If you only want to scale a button, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612738/how-to-create-customlabelfield-which-suites-for-all-blackberry-version/1650712#1650712) will help you.

Comment: Just wondering if I can have one set of high resolution images and scale them for different resolutions. There does'nt seem to be a high level api for this ?

Comment: I always go with a different set of assets(images) for each screen size, rather than using only one set and scaling to screen size. The BlackBerry App World lets you submit builds for each device(set of devices).

Comment: And, to answer your question, you can use the scaleImage32() method from the EncodedImage class to resize your images, but I would recommend going with different set of assets for each screen size.