# How to compress image in blackberry for different screen resolution?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing blackberry application for different model like 8230,8300,9700. Each device having different screen size 240x320,320x240,480x360 etc..  I am using image button in this appllication that means i am setting button background as image. so i am using three different size of image like 100x30 , 120x35 and 160x40 for different model respectively. My question is How to use single image to for all screen resolution that means image size should be compress automatically based on screen size(like Android device compressing). Is any idea to overcome my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578725/how-to-create-image-buttons-that-scale-across-multiple-resolutions/5579855#5579855).

But I really wouldn't recommend using the same image and scaling it to fit the screen size. Use different set of images for each screen size!

If you have your heart set on using only one image(set of images), I think it's better to use the large image(s) and scale down.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I want to know something like , Is there any problem will face to scaling image (In Application performance point of view)?

Comment: I haven't done any measurements to see how much it will take to scale an image, but it definitely takes longer than not scaling the image. So, the answer is yes, it affects the performance. The question would be: by how much? And I don't have an answer for that. It depends on a lot of things.